# Where does the PROCESS_LOCAL task comes from?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am curious about this task locality of the spark. From the log of the driver:

```
18/02/27 10:59:11 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 20 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at TraceTopologyHandler.scala:44) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
18/02/27 10:59:11 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 20 tasks
18/02/27 10:59:11 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSetManager: Epoch for TaskSet 1.0: 1
18/02/27 10:59:11 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSetManager: Valid locality levels for TaskSet 1.0: NODE_LOCAL, NO_PREF, ANY
18/02/27 10:59:11 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_1.0, runningTasks: 0
18/02/27 10:59:11 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, 192.168.254.45, executor 0, partition 0, NODE_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
18/02/27 10:59:11 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, 192.168.254.44, executor 1, partition 1, NODE_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
18/02/27 10:59:11 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 192.168.254.45, executor 0, partition 2, NODE_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
18/02/27 10:59:11 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8, 192.168.254.44, executor 1, partition 6, NODE_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
```

Above logs shows that the taskSet only have three locality levels: NODE_LOCAL, NO_PREF, ANY, and for now it looks good, But

```
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_1.0, runningTasks: 3
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSetManager: No tasks for locality level NODE_LOCAL, so moving to locality level NO_PREF
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSetManager: Moving to ANY after waiting for 0ms
18/02/27 10:59:13 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 12, 192.168.254.45, executor 0, partition 3, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 12 on executor id: 0 hostname: 192.168.254.45.
18/02/27 10:59:13 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 9.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 9) in 95 ms on 192.168.254.45 (executor 0) (4/20)
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_1.0, runningTasks: 3
18/02/27 10:59:13 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 13, 192.168.254.44, executor 1, partition 4, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
18/02/27 10:59:13 TRACE protocol.MessageDecoder: Received message OneWayMessage: OneWayMessage{body=NettyManagedBuffer{buf=PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 13, widx: 2689, cap: 4096)}}
18/02/27 10:59:13 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) in 1924 ms on 192.168.254.44 (executor 1) (5/20)
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 13 on executor id: 1 hostname: 192.168.254.44.
18/02/27 10:59:13 DEBUG scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_1.0, runningTasks: 3
18/02/27 10:59:13 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 14, 192.168.254.45, executor 0, partition 5, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4625 bytes)
```

[image]

I am reading the source code of the spark but can't get the answer where does the PROCESS_LOCAL locality come from. As far as I know, the PORCESS_LOCAL task got empty data and it just run for nothing. Please help, any help must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find the code, which changes the NO_PREF to PROCESS_LOCAL.
The dequeueTask method in TaskSetManager.scala will change the task in NO_PREF to PROCESS_LOCAL locality.